# In this phrase "none of + plural noun", why can the predicate use both singular form and plural form?

Tags: predicate

> None of my friends ever ***come*** to see me.
>
> None of these ***appeal*** to me.
>
> But none of them ***owns*** the landscape.

In this phrase "none of + plural noun", why can the predicate use both singular form and plural form?

Comment: I think the last one should be "But none of them *own* the landscape.".

Answer (score 1):

Very good question.

It can take *both* singular and plural form. OALD defines it -

> [none](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/none_1) - **not one (is singular)** of a group of people or things; **not any (could be plural)** - *any can be used with plural [any suggestions?]*

As exactly mentioned in examples there...

> *None of these pens **works/work*** 
>   *We have three sons but none of them **lives/live** nearby*